# Issue importing ip address inside csv file to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, csv

I am working on SQL bulk copy window application where I need to import csv file into SQL server. But there seems to problem with ip address data.

Csv file data is comma separated and sample data is as below

```
Email,FirstName,LastName,Company,Address1,Address2,City,State/Province,Zip/PostalCode,Country,Phone,SecondaryPhone,Fax,DateEntered,OriginalIP,LatestIP
ab@outlook.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,2/29/16 15:56,12.251.217.166,12.251.217.166
bc@gmail.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,2/29/16 15:57,70.57.244.202,70.57.244.202
```

But When imported, everything is okay except last two columns ie lastip and latestip..

Value being imported are

```
12.2512,12.2512 for 1st row and same for 2nd row ie. 70.5724    ,70.5724
```

code is as below

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                // Creates and opens an ODBC connection
                string strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + this._dirCsv.Trim() + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False";
                string sqlSelect;
                OdbcConnection conn;
                conn = new OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());
                conn.Open();

                //Creates the select command text
                if (numberOfRows == -1)
                {
                    sqlSelect = "select * from [" + this.FileNevCsv.Trim() + "]";
                }
                else
                {
                    sqlSelect = "select top " + numberOfRows + " * from [" + this.FileNevCsv.Trim() + "]";
                }

                //Creates the data adapter
                OdbcDataAdapter objOledbDa = new OdbcDataAdapter(sqlSelect, conn);

                //Fills dataset with the records from CSV file
                objOledbDa.Fill(ds, "csv");

                //closes the connection
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) //Error
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, @"Error - LoadCSV", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return ds;
```

.
    schema.ini is as below

```
[CONTACTS Jan Feb 2016 New.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(,)
MaxScanRows=25
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

and schema write code is as below

```
private void WriteSchema()
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(this._dirCsv + "\\schema.ini", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter srOutput = new StreamWriter(fsOutput);
                string s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;

                s1 = "[" + this.FileNevCsv + "]";
                s2 = "ColNameHeader=" + chkFirstRowColumnNames.Checked.ToString();
                s3 = "Format=" + this._strFormat;
                s4 = "MaxScanRows=25";
                s5 = "CharacterSet=" + this._strEncoding;

                srOutput.WriteLine(s1.ToString() + "\r\n" + s2.ToString() + "\r\n" + s3.ToString() + "\r\n" + s4.ToString() + "\r\n" + s5.ToString());
                srOutput.Close();
                fsOutput.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"writeSchema");
            }
            finally
            { }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like somewhere the IP address is parsed / interpreted as decimal number... What is the datatype of the target column in the database?

Comment: nvarchar(4000) is datattype.. but even If i load data into grid.. you see above code is to load data.. there also same output

Comment: Could you -- for testing purposes -- try to put (double?) quotes around the IP addresses in the first 2 or 3 lines and see what gives?
IMHO the problem is not related to MSSQL but rather to how the `Microsoft Text Driver` interprets the file content. If you don't have a schema.ini file sitting next to the file, then the driver will try 'its best' to figure out what it's trying to read. Since it seems to be wrong about the last columns you might try adding a schema.ini file (cf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This is probably due to the Text driver erroneously interpreting your un-quoted data as a numeric. You can try putting quotes around the field or use a schema.ini file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I already have schema.ini file. I have updated in question

Comment: @Mahajan344, have you faced the issue that OdbcDataReader can read only 255 characters? I am facing this issue now. I put the Text length in Schema.ini but it still take only 255 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @les-h and @deroby
adding column datatype to schema file solved this

Here is updated schema file

```
[CONTACTS Jan Feb 2016 New.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=Delimited(,)
MaxScanRows=25
CharacterSet=ANSI
Col1="Email" Text
Col2="FirstName" Text
Col3="LastName" Text
Col4="Company" Text
Col5="Address1" Text
Col6="Address2" Text
Col7="City" Text
Col8="State/Province" Text
Col9="Zip/PostalCode" Text
Col10="Country" Text
Col11="Phone" Text
Col12="SecondaryPhone" Text
Col13="Fax" Text
Col14="DateEntered" Text
Col15="OriginalIP" Text
Col16="LatestIP" Text
```